# How to use OR inside WHERE in laravel Query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm new to laravel and I need help for query in laravel

My Custom Query

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM blogs
    WHERE
    ('$title'=''  OR title='$title')
    AND
    ('$body'='' OR body='$body')";
```

and i create a laravel build query but don't know how to put OR inside WHERE and Put Brackets

```
$posts =  Blog::where('title','LIKE',"%{$title}%")
                            ->Where('body', 'LIKE',"%{$body}%")
                            ->offset($start)
                            ->limit($limit)
                            ->orderBy($order,$dir)
                            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think orWhere is what you're looking for and based off custom query I think you would need `=` instead of `like` unless thats what youre going for, I think it would be something like:

```
->where('title', '=', $title)
->orWhere('title', '=', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `orWhere()`

```
$posts = Blog::where('title', $title)
             ->orWhere('title', $otherTitle)
             ->orderBy($order, $dir)
             ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this give you an idea :)

```
$posts =  Blog::where(function ($query) use($title) {
                         $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$title}%")
                               ->orWhere('title', '=', '$title');
              })
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use($body) {
                       $query->where('body', 'LIKE', "%{$body}%")
                             ->orWhere('body', '=', '$body');
                             })
             ->offset($start)
             ->limit($limit)
             ->orderBy($order,$dir)
             ->get();
```

Not tested...

Comment: Nice answer, but you miss `use ($title)` and `use ($body)`

Comment: Thank you  @WahyuKristianto , Updated ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts =  Blog::where(function($q) use($title){
              $q->where('title','')->orWhere('title',$title);
         })->where(function($q) use($body){
            $q->where('body','')->orWhere('body',$body);
         })->offset($start)
         ->limit($limit)
         ->orderBy($order,$dir)
         ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like :

```
$result = Blog::where(function($query) use ($title, $body){
      $query->where(
              ["title" => $title, "body"=>$body]
          )->orWhere(
              ["title"=>"", "body"=>""]
          ); 
})
->offset($start)
->limit($limit)
->orderBy($order,$dir)
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `->orWhere()` code.

**Note**: You can also make use of magic methods

```
->whereAgeOrPhone(18, 123456789);
```

Answer (score 0):

use orWhere()

```
$blogs= DB::table('Blog')
                ->where('title', 'LIKE', '%{$title}%')
                ->orWhere('body','LIKE', '%{$body}%')
                ->offset($start)
                ->limit($limit)
                ->orderBy($order,$dir)
                ->get();
```

For More Query, You can [visit here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries)